# Javascript function doesn't work when creating a new HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

My HTML:

```
<table id="laboral">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="start"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="end"/></td>
        <td><textarea name="desc"></textarea></td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="saveRow(this);"> + </button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I press the `+` button I create a new row exactly as the first one, but the `onclick` event doesn't work:

Here's the code for saving the values and create the 2 `input`s and the `textarea`:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.type = "button";
button.setAttribute("onclick", "saveRow(this);")
button.innerHTML = "+";
var btn = tr.insertCell(3);
btn.appendChild(button);
```

If I examine the result with Firefox I can see that the first button and the new generated have the same code. But the generated doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please demo it in jsfiddle or something similar?

Comment: Define "it doesn't work".

Comment: If you can, you might switch to JQuery. You can initialize the page with code like this: `$('#laboral').on('click', 'button', saverow);` After that, you just need to add the button. Each of the added buttons will automatically respond to clicks. You might need to make a small changes to saveRow as well.

Comment: @GolezTrol ***NO***. Such a trivial task should ***NOT*** be done with the obsolete technology that is jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is obsolete? What?

Comment: What is jQuery's purpose? To iron out browser incompatibilities. Browsers have been compatible for several years now. Therefore jQuery's purpose is obsolete.

Comment: Browsers have been compatible? What? First of all that's not true, second, JQuery is not only for incompatibilities, but especially for making DOM manipulation easier.

Comment: What is this, the "how many false premises can we fit into a single sentence" game?

Comment: @AntP He is just trolling, or clearly doesn't work in an environment which produces consumer-facing websites. His original point is correct though, no need for jQuery here.

Comment: @RGraham Actually, I work in [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/). I build my own toolbox of specialised functions, and amazingly enough my sites load in a fraction of the time that most sites do. They also work on even the oldest phones, no problem even for their tiny processors. No incompatibilities either, because I *learned JavaScript*.

Comment: Not the place for this. I didn't say that Vanilla JS isn't *possible* it's just that for public-facing websites it's not worthwhile. e.g. I can write a computer program in Assembly. Does that make C, C++, C# obsolete? Definitely not. Does it make life easier? Sure does. No need for elitism here, just useful answers.

Comment: My own toolbox of JS functions is so good it works even on my old rotary dial phone. Because I learned JavaScript too.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than define an event handler for all the buttons you may add, it may be more efficient to defer it to the table. In this case, you'd do this:

```
// this script should be placed after the table on the page, or deferred in some way
document.getElementById('laboral').onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var elem = e.srcElement || e.target;
    if( !elem.tagName) elem = elem.parentNode;
    if( elem.tagName == "BUTTON") {
        var tr = elem;
        // find the row that contains the button
        while(tr.tagName != "TR") tr = tr.parentNode;
        tr.parentNode.insertBefore(tr.cloneNode(true),tr.nextSibling);
    }
};
```

Done ^_^